# Algebraic way to show $112\sqrt{3}n^2-112\sqrt{3}-21n+112$ is positive for $n\ge 1$

Tags: functions, inequality

As in the title, i am looking for a nice algebraic way to show $112\sqrt{3}n^2-112\sqrt{3}-21n+112$ is positive for $n\ge 1$. Without appealing to derivatives if possible. I am not sure if this possible but I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It is quadratic. Complete the square. Looks like it results in $(32\sqrt{3}n-3)^2-\sqrt{3081-1024\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Please show your preliminary efforts.  Also, do the coefficients have a common factor that can be divided by to simplify the expression?  If you are lost, please show similar problem(s) that your class tackled, or that a textbook presented, along with your work on these problem(s).

Comment: @totoro if that's the nices it can get, I think I will just appeal to the derivative. Show that the function is positive for $n=1$ and that is always increasing for $n>1$. Seems to me to be cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: If you only need the claim for $n$ integer $n>0$, then another alternative is, that maybe is more clear: Compute its value at $n=1$ and show that it is positive. Then compute $p(n+1)-p(n)=224 \sqrt{3} n + 112 \sqrt{3}- 21$, and show that this is positive for $n>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole thing is equal to: 
$$112\sqrt{3}n(n-1)+(112\sqrt{3}-21)(n-1)+91\geq 91 >0.$$

Comment: Wow, this works, how did you come up with this? Thank you! exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: you just need to play around with it in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

$p=112 \sqrt 3 n^2 -112\sqrt 3-21n + 21 +91=112 \sqrt 3 (n^2-1) -21(n-1)+91=(n-1)[(n+1)( 112 \sqrt 3-21)] +91$

$112 \sqrt 3 > 21$

So fo $n=1,.. or..n>1 $ ,.. $p>0$